# QtWebEngine Quicknano has no Sound in Embedded Linux

Tags: html, qt, embedded-linux, yocto, qtwebengine

I have compiled QtWebEngine into my i.MX6 embedded device.  When I tried to play youtube Video with quicknanobrowser, the video plays but there would be no sound.  In fact, there is no sound when I try to test play the audio files in [hpr.dogphilosophy.net/test](http://hpr.dogphilosophy.net/test/) even though the website said that the browser codec is supported.

I have enabled pulseaudio, gstreamer, ffmpeg, opus, vpx, libwebp and yet still no sound.

However, I could play video with gst-launch and there would be sound.

Is it something wrong with quicknanobrowser that does not enable sound?  Or is there components that I need to add to the embedded system?

Edit: Alsa and pulseaudio, GStreamer are all working fine with sound.

Comment: Firstly play test sound via `aplay test.wav` command also test the `amixer`. If both are working then for your device `ALSA` is working and can think of further options.

Comment: I have tested Alsa before installing QtWebEngine. Alsa works via aplay and amixer.  What are the further options?

Comment: I'm also using quicknanobrowser but I the app is crashing when trying to play the youtube videos. Can you please tell me how to launch the quicknanobrowser; I mean the options with which you're able to play the youtube videos?

Comment: @surendranath Please create a new question :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to force `QtWebEngine` to use ALSA. In embedded systems, it is disabled by default.

In `qt5.7/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/media/media.gyp`, there is a test to check if we are on an embedded system:

```
  # Enable ALSA and Pulse for runtime selection.
  ['(OS=="linux" or OS=="freebsd" or OS=="solaris") and ((embedded!=1 and chromecast==0) or is_cast_desktop_build==1)', {
    # ALSA is always needed for Web MIDI even if the cras is enabled.
    'use_alsa%': 1,
    'conditions': [
      ['use_cras==1', {
        'use_pulseaudio%': 0,
      }, {
        'use_pulseaudio%': 1,
      }],
    ],
  }, {
    'use_alsa%': 0,
    'use_pulseaudio%': 0,
  }],
```

I changed last `use_alsa%` to `1` and in `qt5.7/qtwebengine/src/core/config/embedded_linux.pri`, I added a new flag:

```
use_alsa=1
```

With this settings I have audio on my embedded ARM Linux and with flag:

```
enable_webrtc=1
```

I am able to start a WebRTC session with video and audio.